# Oracle SQL return 0 count if there are no orders between dates

Tags: sql, oracle, count

```
select trunc(a.submitted_date,'HH') thehour
     , count(1) count_in_hour 
from your_order a 
LEFT JOIN my_order b ON a.order_id = b.order_id 
where a.state!='INCOMPLETE' 
  and b.substatus != 'DUMMY_IGNORE_INVENTORY' 
  and a.submitted_date>=trunc(to_date('20/01/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) 
  and a.submitted_date<=trunc(to_date('21/01/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) 
  group by trunc(a.submitted_date,'HH') 
  order by thehour asc;
```

I need to get count of orders between date, This returns me

```
21-JAN-18 00:00:00 | 3
21-JAN-18 01:00:00 | 4
21-JAN-18 02:00:00 | 5
21-JAN-18 03:00:00 | 6
21-JAN-18 04:00:00 | 7
21-JAN-18 08:00:00 | 7
21-JAN-18 09:00:00 | 4
21-JAN-18 10:00:00 | 9
```

I am not getting the results for 5,6 and 7 hours as there are no orders placed between this time but I need a query to return the count as 0 even if the orders are not placed in this time.

Like I need 24 rows as there are 24 hours between the dates

Comment: Add a tag of your sql language

Comment: I could imagine that `start with` and `connect by` could be a way to solve it. only if you works with oralce db

Comment: @hotfix you changed the query while formatting it , I think it is misleading. And differs from OP's query

Comment: @Rohit, i had optimized it, but i have changed it back to the original query. the sense has not changed

Comment: IMHO, optimization should be in answer not edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Approach:

Taking your base query and expecting that it will give result in the below format

thehour  count_in_hour
"21-JAN-18 00:00:00"  3
"21-JAN-18 01:00:00"  4

I am writing a sub query which generate 24 hrs for the same date and doing a right join with the above result. So even if you query is not getting data for all 24 hours you will get an entry from this sub query.

Sub query:

Try the below query.

```
 select 
  to_char(to_date('21-JAN-18 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy  HH24:MI:SS') + (level-1)/24, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') as col1 
  from dual
  connect by level <=24;
```

Over All Query:

```
select 
  t2.col1,
  decode(t1.count_in_hour,null,0,t1.count_in_hour)  as count_in_hour
  from 
  (

 SELECT
    trunc(
        a.submitted_date,
        'HH'
    ) thehour,
    COUNT(1) count_in_hour
FROM
    your_order a
    LEFT JOIN my_order b ON a.order_id = b.order_id
WHERE
        a.state != 'INCOMPLETE'
    AND
        b.substatus != 'DUMMY_IGNORE_INVENTORY'
    AND
        a.submitted_date >= trunc(TO_DATE('20/01/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') )
    AND
        a.submitted_date <= trunc(TO_DATE('21/01/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') )
GROUP BY
    trunc(
        a.submitted_date,
        'HH'
    )) t1 right join 
    (select 
  to_char(to_date('21-JAN-18 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy  HH24:MI:SS') + (level-1)/24, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') as col1 
  from dual
  connect by level <=24 
  ) t2 on  t1.thehour = to_date(t2.col1,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') order by t2.col1;
```

Comment: I'm getting below error ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @sujay - this is good answer, you only need to put minimum effort to adjust date formats. Here is **[working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1186)**.

Comment: @sujay, edited my answer and also gave the explanation of my approach. Please try once more.

Comment: @AnkitMongia It's working..Thanks a lot Ankit, Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate hour table, which is holding the 24 hours and need to join with that table to see hours with 0 counts.

```
CREATE TABLE OrderHours
(
OrderHour CHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO OrderHours values('00'),('01')..,('24');


select h.OrderHour, count(*)
                count_in_hour from OrderHour as h LEFT JOIN your_order a on h.OrderHour = trunc(a.submitted_date,'HH')  LEFT JOIN my_order b ON a.order_id = b.order_id where a.order_id = b.order_id 
                and a.state!='INCOMPLETE' and b.substatus != 'DUMMY_IGNORE_INVENTORY' 
                and a.submitted_date>=trunc(to_date('20/01/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) 
                and a.submitted_date<=trunc(to_date('21/01/2018 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) group by h.OrderHour order by thehour asc;
```

Comment: @hotfix, was in a rush. I provided at high level. will update with better approach of using temporary table or common table expression.